# How to select data from multiple tables based on different time ranges?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, charts

I have two tables in MySQL:

- visits
- points

`visits` table looks like the following:

```
+-------+-------------------+-----------+
|   id  |   date            |  user_id  |
+-------+-------------------+-----------+
|   1   |2014-08-01 05:23:00|       43  |
|   2   |2014-08-01 14:41:00|       21  |
|   3   |2014-08-02 23:54:00|       43  |
|   4   |2014-08-03 03:21:00|       43  |
|   5   |2014-08-03 04:19:00|       34  |
|   6   |2014-08-03 11:33:00|       43  |
|   7   |2014-08-04 12:21:00|       43  |
|   8   |2014-08-05 01:55:00|       43  |
|   9   |2014-08-06 06:13:00|       43  |
|  10   |2014-08-07 19:47:00|       43  |
+-------+-------------------+-----------+
```

`points` table looks like the following:

```
+-------+-------------------+-----------+-------+----------+
|   id  |   date            |  user_id  | points|   status |
+-------+-------------------+-----------+-------+----------+
|   1   |2014-08-01 04:33:00|       43  |   10  |        0 |
|   2   |2014-08-02 05:21:00|       21  |   23  |        0 |
|   3   |2014-08-02 09:01:00|       43  |   32  |        1 |
|   4   |2014-08-02 01:21:00|       43  |   21  |        0 |
|   5   |2014-08-03 23:23:00|       34  |   54  |        0 |
|   6   |2014-08-04 20:34:00|       43  |   11  |        0 |
|   7   |2014-08-04 17:54:00|       43  |    9  |        0 |
|   8   |2014-08-04 03:45:00|       43  |   34  |        0 |
|   9   |2014-08-06 08:23:00|       43  |   76  |        0 |
|  10   |2014-08-07 11:43:00|       43  |   52  |        0 |
+-------+-------------------+-----------+-------+----------+
```

I want execute only 1 query and achieve the following.

I'd like to `count` the rows in the `visits` table where the `user_id = 43` and the `date` is between `2014-08-01` and `2014-08-03`.

I also want to `count` the rows, `sum` the `points` in the `points` table where `user_id = 43` and the `date` is between `2014-08-01` and `2014-08-03` and the status is 0.

After that, in the same query, I'd like to select the same as above, but in a different timeframe, like: `2014-08-04` and `2014-08-07`.

Is there any query out there which can solve this problem for me?

(I'm actually doing this because I'd like to get data for one of my jQuery chart which is called: `Morris.js`. I'd like to get 12 datasets if the visitor selects a time range and divide it based on the days, the visitor selected. For example: if he selects: 2014-08-01 till 2014-08-01, I want to display him 12 datasets of that day. But if he selects for example: 2014-08-01 till 2014-08-06, then I'd want to display him the data for the 6 day divided by 12.)

If you don't understand something here, just let me know and I'll explain it better. The point is that I'd like to collet the datasets and draw the chart based on the time range to the visitor. Is that above MySQL logic a good solution for my issue?

### EDIT:

As per request I'm showing the desired result in here:

```
+---------------------+-----------+-------+-------+-------------+
|   date              |  user_id  | points| visits| points_count|
+---------------------+-----------+-------+-------+-------------+
|2014-08-01-2014-08-03|     43    | 31    | 4     | 2           |
|2014-08-04-2014-08-07|     43    | 182   | 4     | 5           |
+---------------------+-----------+-------+-------+-------------+
```

I hope I've calculated everything correctly.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the desired results you want for the sample data you provide.

Comment: Sure, just one moment.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Question updated.

Comment: @Radical_Activity I just posted a query that will do exactly what you were asking along with a demo to show it working :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok so this took a little work because you have to join the two tables independantly of eachother.. the reason being is because one can't have the status of 1 and the other can.. so with that in mind this query will return exactly what you want.

## QUERY:

```
SELECT 
    t.join_date as 'Time Frame',
    t1.user_id,
    t.num_visits,
    t1.num_points,
    t1.total_points
FROM
(   SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN DATE(date) >= '2014-06-01' AND DATE(date) <= '2014-07-10' THEN 1 
            WHEN DATE(date) >= '2014-08-05' AND DATE(date) <= '2014-08-07' THEN 2 
            ELSE 3
        END AS grouping_col,
        CONCAT(MIN(DATE(date)), ' - ', MAX(DATE(date))) as join_date,
        COUNT(id) as num_visits 
    FROM visits 
    WHERE user_id = 43
    GROUP BY grouping_col 
)t
LEFT JOIN 
(   SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN DATE(date) >= '2014-06-01' AND DATE(date) <= '2014-07-10' THEN 1 
            WHEN DATE(date) >= '2014-08-05' AND DATE(date) <= '2014-08-07' THEN 2 
            ELSE 3
        END AS grouping_col,
        CONCAT(MIN(DATE(date)), ' - ', MAX(DATE(date))) as join_date,
        user_id,
        COUNT(id) as num_points,
        SUM(points) as total_points
    FROM points
    WHERE user_id = 43
      AND status = 0
    GROUP BY grouping_col
)t1 ON t1.grouping_col = t.grouping_col
WHERE t.grouping_col IN(1, 2) OR t1.grouping_col IN(1, 2)
```

## NOTE:

you can add as many timeframes to this by just adding more rows to the CASE statement...

## SEE DEMO:

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0c76/14)

Comment: Thank you very much for this query. To be honest this is the one which is the closest to the perfect uery, however it has soe issues as I've tested with the dates. If I cange the dates in the query it gives back false results. I guess something is missing from there. Could you please double check that for me? :)

Comment: @Radical_Activity well what dates are you including and what does it look like? you need to add a new date range in a case statement.. copy one of the rows and do the same thing except make the THEN part increment for each one

Comment: @Radical_Activity if you could edit your question with the exact query you are using i can look at it.

Comment: I'm talking about your fiddle. Try to change the dates, like the second one from `2014-08-04` to `2014-08-05` in both places. It gives back 3 results. Also, when I've played with the dates it gave me back weird results as well.
I have tried it with my data too, and `2014-08-04` - `2014-08-07` gave me back `point` records from `2014-07-26` and `visits` from `2014-07-21`. I'm using the exact same query as your fiddle contains.

Comment: @Radical_Activity Oh ok sorry I made a mistake in the query.. one sec i'm updating it.

Comment: @Radical_Activity ok so you have to have a WHERE clause in here as well.. the WHERE clause at the very end of the query is to go in hand with the case statements so if you add more you will have to add more to the where clause

Comment: @Radical_Activity see this fiddle.. notice the date is changed to 05 instead of 04 and its the correct results stil..... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0c76/9

Comment: Thank you for the update. Yes, now it is working well. However when I check for example `2014-08-03` to `2014-08-03` it doesn't display anything, even when there were 2 visits. Also something is still not okay with the dates. When I change the `DATE(date) <= '2014-08-03'` to 06, it changes both of the results for example. I have tried with my current database, and still the same errors as I've mentioned above. By the way thanks for helping me, this is really something that I'm very in need of.

Comment: @Radical_Activity when its just `2014-08-03` dont compare between the two.. just do `CASE WHEN DATE(date) = '2014-08-03' THEN whatever_number`.... another thing to note you cannot have overlapping dates.. this is for dates that are in a concurrent order. in other words you cannot have two case statements with overlapping dates... it needs to be like a timeline. if you want something like that it will take another two queries.. which isn't worth it

Comment: Alright, thanks for your answer. I have tried to check if it displays if there are `visits` within a timeframe but no `points` and it did not return anything for that. For example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76b8f/2 Also I have tested this code on my DB and its still bad, don't know what could be the problem, because the query is the same.

Answer (score 1):

A better option may be to actually use a stored procedure and set a beginning date param and an end date param so you can pick any dates you want

Answer (score 1):

The only approach which comes to mind is to do two distinct query and use [`UNION ALL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT 
    count(v.id) AS visit_count, 
    count(p.id) AS point_count, 
    sum(p.points) AS points
  FROM visits v1
  JOIN points p1
  ON v1.user_id = p1.user_id
  WHERE v1.user_id = 43
  AND DATE(v1.date) BETWEEN '2014-08-01' AND '2014-08-03'
  AND p1.status = 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    count(v.id) AS visit_count, 
    count(p.id) AS point_count, 
    sum(p.points) AS points
  FROM visits v2
  JOIN points p2
  ON v2.user_id = p2.user_id
  WHERE v2.user_id = 43
  AND DATE(v2.date) BETWEEN '2014-08-04' AND '2014-08-07'
  AND p2.status = 0
) temp
```

Comment: This looks good, however what if I'm creating like 12 of this query? That would be quite an extensive one, I guess.

Comment: Yes, if I'm not mistaken (I'd like somebody else say on this) with union all queries it's like running two separate query and depending on your dataset could be expensive, probably somebody else can come up with a better solution.

Comment: What about a conditional group by? i think that would work.. see what I posted for an example

Comment: I also think conditional group by is the best choice here.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
select count(id)
from visits
join points on points.user_id = visits.user_id
where date between 2014-08-04 00:00:00 and 2014-08-07 00:00:00
and visits.user_id = 43
```